# Resetting / restarting a counter value

Tags: vb.net, counter

I'm using the code below to Count and update a label with the count value.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click  
    Static hits As Integer
    hits += 1 
    Label1.Text = hits.ToString("n0")
End Sub
```

In another button I'm using

```
Label1.Text = 0
```

in an attempt to reset the value. However the value visually resets, but when I click the counter button again it continues to count from where it had left off.

I'd like to be able to reset the value and begin counting from 0 again.

Probably simple enough to figure out, hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `Static` variable. The whole point of a `Static` variable is one accessible only within that method but that retains its value between calls. If you want to be able to reset the value of that variable from elsewhere then it needs to be accessible elsewhere, so it needs to be declared outside all methods, i.e. a member variable AKA a field.

```
Private hits As Integer

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click      

    hits += 1 
    Label1.Text = hits.ToString("n0")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Iv still got a lot to learn, Changed it to `Private hits As Integer` so its no longer static. How would i then change the variable data so it is 0  as using `Label1.text = "0"` still only visual sets the value to 0 and then continues to count.

Comment: The whole point of moving that variable out of the method was so that you can access it from other methods, so access it.  Where you're resetting the `Label`, reset the variable too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably break it out to a separate sub to update the value if you plan on setting the value of the counter and label simultaneously.  Then you can call SetHits(0) from anywhere.

```
Private hits As Integer

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    hits += 1
    SetHits(hits)
End Sub

Private Sub SetHits(num As Integer)
    hits = num
    Label1.Text = hits.ToString("N0")
End Sub
```

Comment: This seams like a Better way But iv made it work now anyway,  Thanks for all your help guys!! =]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, Well made a work around. 
Basicaly i deduct the Value using 
        `hits -= Label1.Text`
`Private hits As Integer` 
 Changed it from Static to Private. So i can access it else where in my form.

`Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    hits += 1 
    Label1.Text = hits.ToString("n0")
End Sub`

`Private Sub RESETBUTTON_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RESETBUTTON.Click

   hits -= Label1.Text
End Sub`

Comment: I'm really not sure why you'd want to subtract the label's text from hits vs setting hits to 0.  You're also not updating the label until you start incrementing the counter again.  If you do intend on keeping the -= text I'd recommend at least using CInt(Label1.Text) vs using an implicit conversion.